# Maven clean install tomcat, no resources

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, server

I have a working eclipse project, it works with the tomcat Server, which is added to eclipse, but when I now try to use it on another pc, it doesn't found resources.

I go to the project directory with the pom.xml and via the command `mvn clean install tomcat7:run` I try to run it. I get the following output.

```
...
[INFO] --- tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.2:run (default-cli) @ Cloud-Datenmanagement ---
[INFO] Running war on http://localhost:8080/Cloud-Datenmanagement
[INFO] Creating Tomcat server configuration at E:\Onedrive\Projekte\SYT_5BHIT\GK9.3\Cloud-Datenmanagement\target\tomcat
[INFO] create webapp with contextPath: /Cloud-Datenmanagement
Nov. 06, 2017 9:29:21 VORM. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFORMATION: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Nov. 06, 2017 9:29:21 VORM. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting service Tomcat
Nov. 06, 2017 9:29:21 VORM. org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFORMATION: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.47
Nov. 06, 2017 9:29:23 VORM. org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFORMATION: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [174] milliseconds.
Nov. 06, 2017 9:29:23 VORM. org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFORMATION: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
```

When I now try to access the site, I get a error message with the description `The requested resource is not available.`

I think, that maven is not including the classes in the war file, but I am not sure and I don't know how to fix it.

Below is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Cloud-Datenmanagement</groupId>
    <artifactId>Cloud-Datenmanagement</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <webResources>
                           <resource>
                               <directory>WebContent</directory>
                            </resource>
                      </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20170516</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.19.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.195</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.test-framework.providers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-provider-jetty</artifactId>
            <version>2.26</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="" docBase="Cloud-Datenmanagement">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>
```

Comment: Do you have a `context.xml`? If so, please post its contents.

Comment: I don't have a context.xml, I tried to create one and set a context with a docBase and even added the web.xml as watched ressource. `<Context path="" docBase="Cloud-Datenmanagement">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
</Context>` But than I get a exception, that the directory does not exists. I am not sure, I work the first time with maven and tomcat, but should not maven generate in tomcat/targate a Directory with the project?